# update jquery ui range slider values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I want to update a jquery ui range slider with the values that are in two text boxes.

```
var minVal = $(this).find('.minTextBox').val();                  
var minVal2 = parseInt(minVal);
var maxVal = $(this).find('.maxTextBox').val();
var maxVal2 = parseInt(maxVal);
var myvalues = [minVal2, maxVal2];

var mySliderId = $(this).find('.RangeSlider').attr('id');

$( "#" + mySliderId).slider({
    range: true,
    values: myvalues,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var idx = $(this).attr("id");
        x = idx.substr(idx.length-2);
        $( "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Min"  + x ).val(ui.values[0]);
        $( "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Max"  + x ).val(ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

I'm trying to pass the myvalues array to the slider to overwrite the old values.

No matter what I try, I can't get this to work. I've looked at various other questions on SO and through the documentation but I can't get any closer.

Am I on the right lines with this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A jsfiddle of the page would be appreciated too.

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/YSEGU/1 .

Comment: I can't really make an accurate fiddle for this. The values for the text boxes are pulled from a database when the page loads and I need my range slider to set itself to the values that are in those text boxes.

Comment: managed to resolve this by doing the following: $('#' + mySliderId).slider("values",0,minVal2);
$('#' + mySliderId).slider("values",1,maxVal2);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize again. execute the below line to modify the range values.

```
$( "#" + mySliderId).slider( "option", "values", myvalues );
```